# Given a degree x, find the nearest degree in an array of degrees

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have an array of degrees, [10, 90, 200, 280, 355] for a circle.

I'm given a degree, let's say 1.  How do I determine that 1 is closest to 355 degrees?

Comment: +1, I had the very same task recently and my solution is a little buggy, so I'm interested to see if there are any other implementations before I try and fix it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Subtract the two numbers. If the difference is larger above 180 [or below -180], subtract [or add] 360. Now you can just compare absolute values of the difference.

Comment: +1 but need to get absolute value of difference and compare to 180 (e.g. could be -200), then subtract from 360.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an actual formula:

```
degreediff = min(abs(x-y),360-abs(x-y))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more compact and efficient:

```
function difference(a, b) {
    var d = Math.abs(a - b);
    return d > 180 ? 360 - d : d;
};

function closest(a, bs) {
    var ds = bs.map(function(b) { return difference(a, b); });
    return bs[ds.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, ds))];
};

> difference(1, 355)
6

> closest(1, [10, 90, 200, 280, 355])
355
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one value which will contain the closes degree found `found_degree` and one for the actual difference `degree_difference`.

Next, iterate over the whole array and calculate two values: `abs(degree_at_position - target_degree)` and `abs(degree_at_position - 360 - target_degree)`. If one of those values is smaller than `degree_difference`, you have a closer degree - store it in `found_degree` and update `degree_difference` accordingly.

That's it.

You maybe should initialise `found_degree` with -1 and `degree_difference` with 360, just to make sure you can properly interpret the result in case of an empty given array as well - or you simply handle the case of an empty input array separately.

Is this a homework, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach would be something like this:

```
var closestElement;
var closestDivergence = 360;

var toCompare = 355;
var choices = [1, 90, 200, 280, 355];

for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++){
    var currentDivergence=choices[i] - toCompare;
    if (currentDivergence<0) {
        currentDivergence+=360;
    }
    if (currentDivergence < closestDivergence){
        closestDivergence = currentDivergence;
        closestElement = i;
    }
}

if (closestElement != NaN){
    alert('Closest value is '+choices[closestElement]);
}
```

Comment: Will not work for values near zero, e.g. 1 is closer to 355 than 10 (per OP).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice little quickie

```
function closest(deg,ar) {
  return ar.sort(function(a,b){var c = deg; return Math.min(360 - (a-c),Math.abs(a-c)) - Math.min(360 - (b-c),Math.abs(b-c))})
}
var myArray = [355, 280, 200, 181, 90, 30];
alert(closest(180,myArray));
```

Sorts and returns the array according to which one is closest to the provided degree.  Index 0 is closest.  It does wrap making 355 closer to 0 than 10.

Answer (score 0):

First check the array (check which element is closest) using the given degree (1 in your example), then add 360 and check with that degree (361). Compare which result is better:

x the given degree, y the first result, z the second result

```
if (abs(x-y) < 360+x-z)
    choose y;
else
    choose z;
```

If the array is sorted you can check it with a binary sort which gives you O(log n) time in worst case scenario. Otherwise you have to browse through the whole array two times.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will only work with circles. It's pseudo code of course.

```
 degree diff = min(abs(x-y),360-abs(x-y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments from this page I managed to come up with this code:

```
function closest(deg, degs) {

deg = (deg / 360 > 1 ? deg - (Math.floor(deg / 360)*360) : deg);

var difference = 360;
var closest = -1;

for(i=0;i<degs.length;i++) {

    var x = degs[i];

    var diff = Math.min(Math.abs(x-deg),360-Math.abs(x-deg))

    if(diff <= difference) {
        closest = i;
        difference = diff;
    }
};

return closest;
```

}

closest(1000, [10, 90, 200, 280, 355]);